# postfix prefix operator overload error c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

When using operator overloading for prefix and postfix increment, I get an error from compiler:

> "Fajl Fajl::operator ++(int)' : member function already defined or declared"

Here are my headers for operator ++:

```
Fajl& operator ++ (); // prefix
Fajl& operator -- (); // prefix
Fajl operator ++ (int); // postfix
Fajl operator ++ (int); // postfix
```

And my implementations:

```
Fajl& Fajl::operator ++ () // prefix
{
    ++(*poz);
    return *this;
}

Fajl& Fajl::operator -- () // prefix
{
    --(*poz);
    return *this;
}

Fajl Fajl::operator ++ (int dummy) // postfix
{
    Fajl temp(*this);
    ++(*this);
    return temp;
}

Fajl Fajl::operator -- (int dummy) // postfix
{
    Fajl temp(*this);
    --(*this);
    return temp;
}
```

"Fajl" is the class, and "poz" its argument which I'm incrementing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take another look in the header file, isn't that two postfix `++` overloads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Fajl operator ++ (int); // postfix
Fajl operator ++ (int); // postfix
              ^^
           should be --
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to be sure, but perhaps it's referring to the fact that you've duplicated the declaration for postfix increment:

```
Fajl operator ++ (int); // postfix
Fajl operator ++ (int); // postfix
```

Presumably one of those was suppose to be `--` instead of `++`. That quite likely leads to another problem: you've apparently *defined* an `operator--`, but it's not declared in the class definition. If it hasn't yet, the compiler will almost certainly complain about that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 identical declarations of Fajl operator ++ (int); Correct the 2nd one to operator--